# How to get selected radio value using Bootstrap radio button groups and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap radio button groups and am having a hard time getting the selected value into my controller. I have a small snippet of JS to set the selection on which button was clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form .btn-group label').on('click', function() {
        $(this).find('input').prop('checked', true);
    });
});
```

Here is example HTML:

```
<form name="add-form" ng-submit="addFavorites()" novalidate>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Color</label>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn">
            <input type="radio" name="color" value="red" class="form-control" ng-model="favorites.color" ng-required="true">Red
        </label>
       <label class="btn">
            <input type="radio" name="color" value="blue" class="form-control" ng-model="favorites.color" ng-required="true">Blue
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Now when I submit this with ng-submit to this function, I do not get any console logged values for my radio buttons.

```
$scope.addFavorites = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.favorites, function(value, key) {
        console.log(key, value);
    });
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried declaring $scope.favorites = {} in the controller ?
Explanation: if $scope.favorites is not declared, you'll not be able to access the element "color" of an undefined element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You do not need this code:

   ```
   (document).ready(function() {
     $('form .btn-group label').on('click', function() {
       $(this).find('input').prop('checked', true);
     });
   });
   ```

Your radio button is wrapped with its label so HTML5 will propagate click from the label to the radio.

2. Initialize your `$scope.favorites` object to `{}`

That is it, in submit you can get your `$scope.favorites` object with all its arguments.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/OatdIsvCUBSniHHQFyxG?p=preview